# How to embed and override a struct in Go

Tags: go, data-structures, heap

I am constructing the min/max heaps of ints to satisfy the interface from `container/heap`.

The min heap works well such as

```
type MinHeapInt []int

func (h MinHeapInt) Len() int {
    return len(h)
}

func (h MinHeapInt) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return h[i] < h[j]
}

func (h MinHeapInt) Swap(i, j int) {
    h[i], h[j] = h[j], h[i]
}

func (h *MinHeapInt) Peek() interface{} {
    return (*h)[0]
}

func (h *MinHeapInt) Push(x interface{}) {
    *h = append(*h, x.(int))
}

func (h *MinHeapInt) Pop() interface{} {
    length := len(*h)
    res := (*h)[length - 1]
    *h = (*h)[0 : length - 1]
    return res
}
```

Now I am trying to develop the max heap by only overriding the `Less` method.

The first solution does not work since it cannot find the array

```
type MaxHeapInt struct {
    MinHeapInt
}

func (h MaxHeapInt) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return h[i] > h[j]
}
```

The second solution only keeps the `Less` method.

```
type MaxHeapInt MinHeapInt

func (h MaxHeapInt) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return h[i] > h[j]
}
```

Wonder if there is anyway to get around. Thanks!

Comment: There is a 3rd option with your type declaration for go 1.10
type MaxHeapInt = MinHeapInt

Comment: @ZachTaylor: that's not what a [type alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations) (from go1.9) is for, it doesn't allow you to change any methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first solution is trying to index the `MaxHeapInt` struct, not the `MinHeapInt` slice.

```
type MaxHeapInt struct {
    MinHeapInt
}

func (h MaxHeapInt) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return h.MinHeapInt[i] > h.MinHeapInt[j]
}
```

If you want them to be initialized the same, then create a partial heap implementation, and wrap in the desired struct (similar to the [wrapper example](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#example__sortWrapper) in the sort package).

```
type Max struct{ IntHeap }

func (h Max) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return h.IntHeap[i] > h.IntHeap[j]
}

type Min struct{ IntHeap }

func (h Min) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return h.IntHeap[i] < h.IntHeap[j]
}

type IntHeap []int

func (h IntHeap) Len() int { return len(h) }

func (h IntHeap) Swap(i, j int) { h[i], h[j] = h[j], h[i] }

func (h *IntHeap) Peek() interface{} { return (*h)[0] }

func (h *IntHeap) Push(x interface{}) {
    *h = append(*h, x.(int))
}

func (h *IntHeap) Pop() interface{} {
    length := len(*h)
    res := (*h)[length-1]
    *h = (*h)[0 : length-1]
    return res
}

// Now these can be initialized like
//     Min{IntHeap{1, 2, 3}}
//     Max{IntHeap{1, 2, 3}}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me! However, the `MaxHeapInt` seems still not a good one. No sure if there I could find better way.

Comment: @dapangmao: what do you mean by "not a good one"? What are you looking for?

Comment: The `MaxHeapInts` works but has to be called such as `var maxHeap = &MaxHeapInt{MinHeapInt{1, 5, 3}}`, which is different from `var minHeap = &MinHeapInt{1, 5, 3}`.